What is a connected function with a fixed point in A000081
Very short question, which I ask because the ressources on Oeis did not help:
What is meant by a connected function with fix point on https://oeis.org/A000081 ?
Maybe I missed something but I do not think that it is explained on the page...

Consider a function $f$ from $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ to itself. This can be seen as a  graph on the vertex set $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ by drawing an edge $i \to f(i)$ for all $i$. Then the hypothesis "one fixed point" on $f$ translates into "exactly one loop" for the graph. The connectedness hypothesis is directly on the graph. Because there are only $n-1$ edges (not counting the loop), the graph is necessarily a tree. It is rooted at the loop. So this kind of function amounts to a rooted tree.

Great, thank you, that makes sense!
